# ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube

My SonarQube starts normally, but when I try to connect with my browser, I got a

> ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Can someone help me? Maybe a conf to accept remotes connections? My server distribution :

```
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 6.0.7 (squeeze)
Release:        6.0.7
Codename:       squeeze
```

I'm currently using java version "1.8.0_45". When I try to connect to sonar, I use : server_ip:9000/sonar address. I try server_ip:9000 to but exactly the same issue. I got no log in access.log file. It's really strange...

Comment: There is too little informations, such as which OS are you using and which JRE/JDK are you using, which could help answer your question. And coudl you add some information about why you entered you specific address in the browser address bar ? (such as message log, indicating the successful start of you application and where it tells you the correct )address of your application )

Comment: How can you tell your SonarQube has started properly ?

Comment: When I watch sonar.log file, it say :                                               2015.04.24 11:06:44 INFO  web[o.s.s.a.TomcatAccessLog] Web server is started
2015.04.24 11:06:44 INFO  web[o.s.s.a.EmbeddedTomcat] HTTP connector enabled on port 9000
2015.04.24 11:06:44 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[web] is up

Comment: You should check firewall settings, see if port 9000 is open - and check that another process is not using it (on Debian, several apps compete for this port).